# Getting issue while parsing the JSON String with special characters

Tags: jquery, json

I tried to parse using JSON.parse(jsonString) but it is giving me an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 258 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

```js
[{
  "LOB_COMPLAINT_CLASS_MATRIX_ID": 86395,
  "COMPLAINT_TYPE_ID": 1340,
  "COMPLAINT_TYPE": "a ag test",
  "LOB_BEN_ID": "20044",
  "DATA_ROOT_PATH": "blm description",
  "COMPLAINT_CLASS_ID": "1172",
  "COMPLAINT_CLASS": "~!@#$%^*()_+{}:"<>??>",
  "IS_ACTIVE": true,
  "PAGE_NO": 1,
  "PREVIOUS_VALUE": 86396,
  "NEXT_VALUE": 86374,
  "FilterString": ""
}]
```

Comment: It seems that JSON is wrong . Please post error what you having.

Comment: The JSON is invalid. Use something like json lint to find the issues.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an array containing an object. As such you have mis-matched quotes in the `COMPLAINT_CLASS` value. Use ```\``` to escape the double quote in the string (assuming it is actually JSON in your working case) or change the delimiting quotes to `'` instead of `"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — It looks like a JSON text to me.

Comment: it boils down to `"COMPLAINT_CLASS": """`  (3 quotes) which is not *valid* json.  Even the snippet shows this  as `<>??>` are a (very slightly) different colour.  The error message is very helpful in pointing this out for you.

Answer (score -1):

This line causes the problem:

`"COMPLAINT_CLASS": "~!@#$%^*()_+{}:"<>??>",` because you have double quotes inside the value, replace it with `"~!@#$%^*()_+{}:\"<>??>"` and you should  be fine. I've added an escape character before the double quote that's inside.

Comment: JSON strings must be quoted with `"`. Using `'` there is invalid.